# couldn't find inline method Landroidx/compose/RememberKt

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

При компиляции проекта, единственное, что вызывает ошибку - это строчка:

```kotlin
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(SelectedState.NONE) }
```

Проект вызывает огромную ошибку, в конечном итоге выдающая:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't find inline method Landroidx/compose/RememberKt;.remember(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Что я пробывал:

- Полностью чистил кэш загрузок библиотек
- Следовал [этом советам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759939/couldnt-inline-method-call-remember-into-androidx-compose-runtime-composable)
- Возвращал проект на момент, когда он работал
- Менял версии Kotlin, Java, библиотек, Android Plugin и др
- Вручную добавлял библиотеку `androidx.compose.runtime`

В итоге ошибка никак не исчезла. Мои gradle файлы:

Модульный:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    def name = "com.adisalagic.thedoctorteam"
    compileSdk 32
    defaultConfig {
        namespace name
        applicationId name
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
//    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev10'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev10'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev10'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev10'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
    def nav_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
//    implementation 'com.github.kizitonwose:CalendarView:1.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.videolan.android/libvlc-all
    implementation group: 'org.videolan.android', name: 'libvlc-all', version: '4.0.0-eap2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose/compose-runtime
    implementation 'androidx.compose:compose-runtime:0.1.0-dev14'
}
```

Проекта:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta03'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Настройки:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "TheDoctorTeam"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался простым.

Две библиотеки конфликтуют с собой, поэтому я убрал строчку

```
implementation 'androidx.compose:compose-runtime:0.1.0-dev14'
```